# Форматирование даты JS

Tags: javascript, дата

Как форматировать дату формата 2016-04-16 В 16/04/2014 js средствами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
function to2Digits(n) { return (n<10 ? "0" : "") + n }
var res = to2Digits(d.getDate()) + "/" + to2Digits(d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло.И если не сложно подскажите почему функция getMonth() возвращает месяц не 4-ый а 3-ий

Comment: @quaresma89, потому что они от 0 нумеруются.

Answer (score 1):

```
"2016-04-16".replace(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$/, "$3/$2/$1")
```

Comment: А стандартными функциями даты никак?

Comment: @quaresma89, у тебя в вопросе говорится только о строках. Где там даты?

Comment: @quaresma89, у дат, [как и у чисел](/a/453060/178988), нет формата, он есть только у строкового представления.

Comment: Некорректно вопрос задал согласен. Вообщем это будет объект new Date('2016-04-16'); я могу далее преобразовать в нужный мне формат?